# Converting a DFA to a Universal Turing Machine

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, turing-machines, deterministic

**Question**: Is there a way (algorithm) to convert a deterministic finite automaton (**DFA**) **to** a Turing machine (**TM**)? If so; how can this be done?

**Background**: I am working on encoding Turing machines, and find the task itself to be rather straightforward. However, this is as long as I have been provided with a state diagram (of the transitions).

On the other hand, if I just have the description of said machine, I'm at a loss.

**Example**: Suppose we have a TM that decides:

```
A = {w | w contains an equal number of a's and b's}
```

How do I convert this to an actual Turing Machine? Or rather; how do I map out the transitions functions?

I have drawn the DFA for such a language, and hence; could I convert said DFA to a TM?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really see how it is possible for you to have constructed a DFA for the language A, considering that a^n b^n cannot possibly be recognized using a finite automaton by the pumping lemma.